# "already exists and is not an empty directory" for Empty Directory using Docker

Tags: git, docker

I've been working on a Docker image that pulls necessary files from a github repo and then builds itself. It is intended to just update itself from github each time, but to test it I have been deleting the entire github repo folder each time it runs.

After deleting the folder, I started getting

> fatal: destination path 'Project-4' already exists and is not an
>   empty directory.

The contents of the Dockerfile (the file that builds the image) are:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "git clone https://github.com/nathanhtaylor/Project-4.git && cd ./Project-4 && pip install -r requirements.txt && python server.py"]
```

There is no directory `Project-4` anywhere on this machine. This error happens no matter what folder the image runs out of. Running `git clone http://github.com/nathanhtaylor/Project-4.git` manually works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flaw in the way you are building your Docker image.  Docker images are supposed to be immutable i.e once you build them you should be only able to run it using the built executable and not change it. Docker images are and can be versioned just like your source codes.

In your example you are trying to do the process of build , getting the dependencies and execution all in CMD which is against the principles of how and why containers must be used and the problem they try to solve.

I suggest reading this article to understand why Immutability is required

https://medium.com/sroze/why-i-think-we-should-all-use-immutable-docker-images-9f4fdcb5212f

As to your Dockerfile i would suggest you change it to get the git repository and requirements as part of docker build steps and out of CMD and only keep the executable there.

In the scenario you stated, ideally your CI(continuous integration) or any other pipeline should have a phase to rebuild Docker image from scratch if your remote git repository has any changes and version it accordingly and mark it latest tag.

Also , [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) link has a nice way to building docker images using remote git repositories which might be useful in your scenario if you dont want to use a CI pipeline of sorts.

Comment: All true, but does this explain the observed error?

Comment: Yes, because you are assuming that this is your machine you are running these commands on , whereas infact you are running them on the already built image.

Comment: So? (I also noticed the asker seemed to assume this, but still don't see why git clone should show this error)

Comment: You might want to delete your previous images and try one more time using ```docker rmi``` and see if that makes a difference. Also , use the --no-cache option of docker to ensure it is not using any intermediate images.